# Finding maximum of a correlation in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have to find the parameters theta such that:

[image]

where r is a known vector and phi is a function that uses the parameters from the previous iteration. How can I implement that optimization in Python?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.optimize as optimize


# Gaussian function
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return (1/(sig*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))*np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))


# My observed data is a sum of two gaussians
step = 0.005
numSignals = 2
x = np.arange(0, 3+step, step)
w = np.array([0.4,0.8])
mean = np.array([0.5,0.9])
sigma = np.array([0.1,0.2])
noise = 0.05*np.random.normal(0,1,len(x))
y = w[0]*gaussian(x, mean[0], sigma[0]) + w[1]*gaussian(x, mean[1], sigma[1]) 

#Initialization, I assume my model is a sum of weighted gaussians and it is empty at the beginning


model = 0
i = 0
_mean = np.zeros(numSignals)
_sigma = np.zeros(numSignals)
_w = np.zeros(numSignals)

while i<numSignals:
    r = y - model
    # Optimization step
    J = lambda c: -abs(np.dot(r,gaussian(x,c[0],c[1])))**2
    res = optimize.minimize(J, (0.2, 0.5), method='TNC', tol=1e-6)
    _mean[i] = res.x[0]
    _sigma[i] = res.x[1]
    _w[i] = np.dot(gaussian(x,_mean[i],_sigma[i]),r)/np.dot(gaussian(x,_mean[i],_sigma[i]),gaussian(x,_mean[i],_sigma[i]))
    model = model + _w[i]*gaussian(x,_mean[i],_sigma[i])
    print _w[i],_mean[i],_sigma[i]
    i += 1
```

this is an initialization algorithm to find values for mean, sigma and weights of a signal, that is a sum of two gaussian functions. After the initialization I use another algorithm that works, but this one gets wrong values (even using as initial values for optimize the real values instead of 0.2 and 0.5 I get 0.51 and 0.54 for mean and 2.2e-6 and 2.4e-6 for sigma).

I try to optimize the correlation between a residual (r) and the base functions (gaussian functions) to find the estimated values (_w,_mean,_sigma)

Edit 1: I just try to find the parameters (w,mean and sigma) that maximize the expression above (or minimize the negative in my code) so I find estimations to initialize another algorithm. But despite using the real values as initial values in the minimize method from scipy I get wrong values for mean and sigma.

Edit 2: gaussian function works perfectly... so before commenting, test the code you refer to, and don't try to humiliate people

Comment: You write some codez. Then when you are stuck at a specific point you ask here or at math.stackexchange.com, whichever is more appropriate.

Comment: [Ok](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke)

Comment: Voted to reopen. If you can, please be more clear on "but this one gets wrong values". How and why are they wrong? What's the values and what did you expect?

Comment: Thanks for adding that code. Unfortunately, I do not have expertise in this topic, so I can't offer any assistance. But it would probably help to get your question re-opened if you could add some more explanation of how that equation at the top of your question relates to your code. And it would also be good if you could show _some_ code that attempts to implement that optimization (even if its wrong or inefficient).

Comment: @msw as I mentioned in the post, my gaussian funcion works perfectly

Comment: Currently, you don't use the `noise` you compute. Should it be part of `y`?

Comment: @das-g yes, but I was trying first with the noiseless signal

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a conceptual, SciPy-unrelated problem with your approach. If I understand you correctly, you have data (`y` in your code) that can be explained as the sum of two (unknown) Gaussians. (I.e., `mean` and `sigma` are only given here because you calculate `y` for the sake of example. Usually, `y` would be the result of some measurement.)

You now try to find the parameters of the two Gaussians by first fitting one Gaussian to the data, and then fitting another Gaussian to the difference between that first fit and the data (the residue, in your code `r` in the second iteration). This might approximately give you the underlying Gaussians if one of them was clearly dominating the data. However, in the data you provided, both the influence of both underlying Gaussians has a similar order of magnitude.

Thus, in the first iteration, you'll get one Gaussian that alone best approximates the data. Because it has to 'cover' the effect of *both* underlying Gaussians combined, it cannot be too similar to a single one of them. Trying to then approximate the residue with another (also dissimilar) Gaussian won't rescue you from that.

If you want to get satisfying results, you'll have to fit all parameters of your two-Gaussian-model in one go.

Comment: I am stuck with this, in the first iteration I can get a similar value for the `mean`, but the value of `sigma` is really small, so the value of `(1/(sig*np.sqrt(2*np.pi)))` is huge and so the correlation. That adds error for the next iterations.